# C++ namespace. Как правильно работают namespace?

Tags: c++

У меня есть файл `A.h` в котором есть код:

```
namespace Top 
 {
    namespace Inner
    {
       namespace Bottom {
          class ClassA { ... }
       }
    }
 }
```

А в другом файле `B.h`, похожий код:

```
namespace Top 
 {
    namespace Inner
    {
       namespace Bottom {
          class ClassB { ... }
       }
    }
 }
```

Мой вопрос.

Зачем в разных файлах описывать одинаковые имена `namespace`? Или во время компиляции или компоновки они как-то соединяются в один, и компилятор может понять, что если у нас в файле `A` и `B` есть одинаковые имена, то тогда это один и тот же `namespace`? 
У меня проект более 20 разных файлов с такими же названиями пространства имен, но с разными классами внутри некоторых. 
К тому же, если я захочу подключить к своему проекту `dll`, в которой у меня будет `ClassC` с такой же иерархией имен пространств, будет ли это считаться этим же `namespace` или уже другим? 
Зачем нужно дублировать имена пространств в разных файлах?

Этот вариант можно считать валидным?

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

void func()
{
    Top::Inner::Bottom::ClassA();
    Top::Inner::Bottom::ClassB();
}
```

Comment: Глобальное пространство имен ничем не отличается от каких-либо других пространств имен. Ваш пример объявления классов в пользовательском пространстве имен не содержит абсолютно никаких отличий от повседневной практики объявления классов в глобальном пространстве имен. То, что в данном случае используется какое-то другое пространство имен, ничего не меняет. Поэтому не ясно, что именно вызвало данный вопрос и в чем его суть вообще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дублирование имени `namespace` в разных файлах позволяет достичь..

**Кратко**:

1. Удобства навигации/ориентации в коде.
2. Дополнение существующего пространства имен новыми возможностями.

**Детальней**:

Все мы люди, и все мы устроены так, что не можем держать в голове много вещей одновременно. Гораздо удобнее и для себя, и для других программистов вынести уже "готовые" более менее отлаженные участки кода в отдельный файл (так сказать *подальше, с глаз долой*), чтобы не держать их в голове (кроме того, существуют и правила, что именно можно и нужно выносить в файлы, но это уже отдельная тема). Что же тогда? Придется разделять неймспейс? Не придется, потому что в разных файлах можно прописать одно и тоже имя для `namespace`. Глянем, например, как это делается в Qt (этот код создается по умолчанию при создании формы/диалогового окна):

mainwindow.h

```
namespace Ui {
//--------^^
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    // поля и методы
};
```

aboutform.h

```
namespace Ui {
//--------^^
class AboutDialog;
}

class AboutDialog: public QDialog
{
    // поля и методы
};
```

Обратите внимание, что имя пространства имен одинаковое. Благодаря этой возможности дополняется существующее пространство имен (которое могло быть объявлено где-то ранее).

Кроме всего прочего, используя, как Вы сказали, дублирование имени, можно расширить уже существующее пространство имен без его перекомпиляции. Никто не запрещает Вам сделать вот так:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace std {
    const int my_custom_value = 999;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "My custom std value = " << std::my_custom_value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

И получить на экране:

```
My custom std value = 999
```

А представьте, сколько это времени экономит, ведь нам не нужно пересобирать **все** пространство имен.

Comment: более менее ясно. спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Это будет всё равно одно и то же пространство имён, вы всего навсего его дополняете, компилятор понимает, что это одно и то же, главное правильно обращаться к классам. "Зачем в разных файлах описывать одинаковые именна namespace?" Разницы практически нет, а вот целесообразно ли это, это уже решать вам.
Ваш вариант считается валидным.